# Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad

Tags: python, list, numpy, tensor

I have a variable `losses_all = []` that I want to convert to an np.array. I tried to do so using the code and got the following error:

```
# convert to numpy array
losses = np.array(losses_all)

# ERROR MESSAGE
RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.
```

I also tried this but get the following error:

```
# using code from error message above
losses=losses_all.detach().numpy()

# NEW ERROR MESSAGE
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'detach'
```

Is there another way to convert this variable to an array?

Answer (score 5):

You are calling numpy array on list variable. If your list losses_all have different tensor values, then

Call like this:

```
losses= [ loss.detach().numpy() for loss in losses_all]
```